# Gujarat Fonts - Indic

Tags: 10.10, fonts

Sir,
I need to install Gujarat Fonts - INDIC. From where shell I get the concerned font file to install? I had previously Win XP and the fonts were installed but the same is not applicable for the Ubuntu. In indic case there is a facility to type gujarati as per the pronounciation using english alphabets and also gives display at a corner for guidance that which character required to be typed. Please suggest how to avail the same facility in this Ubuntu.

Comment: ttf-gujarati-fonts ?

Comment: Navin to use Incic fonts you must have IBus installed and started.. I just now installed Gujarati.. it works fine.. However I think the word hints are not available, but if you are a native speaker it is very easy to type using the Latin (English) alphabet.. You only need to learn the ITRANS key patterns.. They are very simple.. ITRANS = Indian languages TRANSliteration.. they are very intuitive in like a=અ aa=આ etc .. Which system did you use in Windows? Was it a Unicode systeme, or did it just use "Extended"ASCII keys? .. Ubuntu is fully unicode aware. Yon only need IBus and choose Gujarati.

Answer (score 2):

IBus is perfect solution for you.
See this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus

Comment: IBus is an input method. It has nothing to do with fonts.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Many(most) people don't understand the distinction... Script, Font, Input method, IBus, ITRANS, Transliterations, Virtual keyboard, Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16... Initially all these things can be a mystery to people... It's quite possible he just means, "How can I get Ubuntu to allow me to type in my language of choice." ... If IBus isn't running, nothing will work.. and if it is running Gujarati is available by default, as are many other scripts (and their fonts), you simply need to select it via IBus.

Comment: @fred.bear: I guess you're right… I hadn't carefully read the "facility to type gujarati" part of the question and was going just by its title and first few sentences. Oh well. I've upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Navin, I guess the [Google](http://www.google.com/transliterate/) IME is not available on linux, so even If you use some software like [Baraha](http://www.baraha.com/) - on windows, then you can emulate its benavior on Linux using wine, since you're using Ubuntu its easy to install WINE (http://www.winehq.org/) through Synaptic.

1. Go to System - Admin - Synaptic Package Manager
2. Search and locate wine - Click on Radio button- Click on apply
   changes - Thus wine will be installed
3. Download latest software from [Baraha][4] or likes of it.
4. and open it through wine...and get the job done.